# non-delivery errors on internally sent emails to newly created user

Tags: email, exchange-2007

After I had to delete and recreate a user account in Exchange 2007, I am getting a non-delivery error, on internally sent emails to this newly created user. This is happening for all users who try to send emails to this one user.

Also I'm able to send email to this new user if I reply to his email.

This is how error looks like:

```
IMCEAEX-_O=EXCHANGENAME_OU=EXCHANGE+20ADMINISTRATIVE+20GROUP+20+28NFDVBOHF22RRTLT+29_CN=RECIPIENTS_CN=User19ax23be6@domainname.com
#550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.ExRecipNotFound; not found ##
```

Comment: This is (most likely) a misconfiguration on the user's account in Exchange.  Voting to migrate to ServerFault.com.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't fully purge the original account you deleted from the system before recreating the account.  I would just start the process over from scratch.

Comment: what do you suggest? I don't know how else could I "fully purge" the original account.

Comment: Did you have exchange 2000 or 2003 before you had 2007 by any chance? If so was the original mailbox already there at that time?

Comment: no, I haven't had exchange before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook is trying to send mail to that user using a X500-address (even if you type in "User19ax23be6@domainname.com"). After deleting the mailbox and recreating it the old X500 address is not valid anymore while Outlook cached it. The best way to solve this issue is to add the old X500-address to that mailbox like this:

1. In Exchange Management Console find the mailbox you recreated
2. Right-click on it and select properties
3. Go to the E-Mail-Addresses-Tab
4. Select "Add->Custom address"
5. In the type-field enter X500
6. In the address-field enter this "/O=Exchangename/OU=Exchange Administrative Group (NFDVBOHF22RRTLT)/CN=Recipients/CN=User19ax23be6"

If you changed anything in the error message, you need to check the address in 6. If you didn't it should work like that. Note that leaving out the domain is on purpose here.

Same thing, with a little more explanation:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/exchange/exchange-e-mail-addresses-and-the-outlook-address-cache/

Comment: Coincidence.. I solved the problem 15 minutes before you posted that. Thx anyway.
with that: https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/exchange/exchange-e-mail-addresses-and-the-outlook-address-cache/

Comment: I was wondering, how long should I let that old address in?
I already tried deleteing nk2 file in outlook, but with no difference.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Which Outlook version are you using?

Comment: MS Outlook 2010

Comment: Outlook 2010 does not use nk2-files for storing the nickname/autocompletecache. You can find further information here: http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=http://www.msxfaq.de/clients/nicknamecache.htm

Comment: my bad.. i have 2007, there is 2010 version on client computer, which is working fine. I think the link you paste it will do for my outlook version also.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a client / sender error.

In Outlook, have the user trying to send the email (In this case your self);

1. Open Contacts, delete the user from contacts
2. Start a new email, start to type the user, when the autocomplete pops up hit the delete key on your keyboard to delete the cached address.

What is likely happening is that you have a matching Exchange object for username, email address and the other visible attributes, but when you send the unique IDs are different therefore it can't find the object matching the GUID in the cached contact.

Comment: already tried that, but no difference.

Comment: Did you have to recreate the Exchange and AD objects?

Comment: Only exchange object.

Comment: Ah, I have had to suffer this and I can't recall the final fix as I have not had to fix one of these for a long while, I am asking to move to ServerFault